# DataSnapShot FirebaseDatabase return null , why?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to retrieve data value in a specified note in my database. here is my code

```
        DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USERID);
    DatabaseReference refYear =ref.child(extractYear);
    DatabaseReference refMonth =refYear.child(extractMonth);
    DatabaseReference refDay =refMonth.child(extractDay);
    refDay.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(extractDay)){
                Log.i(TAG, dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG,"Failed to get value ..");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and here is my firebase database

```
{
    "k5yGCSKwjjXxnhCQGuy9jJzdIAu2" : {
         "OverTime" : {
                "2017" : {
                     "12" : {
                             "01" : "2",
                             "02" : "3",
                             "03" : "2",
                             }
                           }
                         }
```

But the code alway give the value of dataSnapShot null . I just dont know why 
. Can you guys explain it pls ? Thank you

Comment: particular day entry isn't a direct child of month.....rather it's child is a map of day/number values.

Comment: so my code didnt point extractly to the right position ? I get ur idea but dont know how to resolve that ? any hint pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment above, you could do something like

```
        Map<String, String> map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if (map != null) {
            String value = map.get("extractDay");
        }
```

Comment: still return null map sir

Comment: just to confirm....if you set breakpoint in `onDataChange` what json does `dataSnapShot` contain?

Comment: also, looks like you might be missing out `OverTime` child?

Comment: ah yes , the OverTime child was missed . this worked . Thank you so much.upvoted you but my reputation less than 15 so it wont public :)